# The critical point of the function $z^4 - 2z^2$ at the $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = z^4 -2z^2$ be a complex polynomial.
We know that $f'(z) = 4z^3 - 4z$,
can I conclude that since $f(\infty) = \infty$, so that $\infty$ is not a critical point?

(Seems like when we are doing complex function,
it is not too hard to generalize all the concepts such as zeros, poles, singularities to the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty$, is there any advantages of doing this, or why don't we just do the complex function on the finite complex plane only?)

Answer (score 0):

The point $\infty$ is a pole, so not a critical point.